# I have forgotten an admin password that is in the database as md5

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin

I have forgotten an admin password that is in the database as md5..  as such I cannot log in as admin to the script... how can I delete old password and replace with new password?

Comment: you got access to the database?

Comment: Yes I have access to the database

Comment: ok, look for the `password` field of that admin user on the database and use this tool http://md5.gromweb.com/ . If you want to recover copy the generated md5 to reverse. Or you can also generate a new one by having a new pass to convert and paste it to the `password` field.

Answer (score -1):

Afaik the only way is to actually hack the db.

Comment: or use a rainbow table... if he finds one that has the actual keyword.

Comment: Yepp thats quite shady buisness. Best would be direct acces to the db then change to a new hash(witch he knows coresponding password for)